# playback of sound written in Assembly by external speakers

Tags: assembly, audio, x86, windows-xp, external

I currently have a code in Assembly that allows me to write a sound and play it. I need to test it on a Windows DualCore 2007 with XP-32 and wired speakers connected to the tower, but the sound comes out of the tower and I can't find a solution to how to make the speakers play the sound.
mon code est le suivant, dans le fichier sound.inc :

```
section .data
    clock dw 0
    time dw 119
    tour dw 0
    frequence dw 0

    Cg dw 9121
    C#g dw 8609
    Dg dw 8126
    D#g dw 7670
    Eg dw 7239
    Fg dw 6833
    F#g dw 6449
    Gg dw 6087
    G#g dw 5746
    Ag dw 5423
    A#g dw 5119
    Bg dw 4831

    C dw 4560
    C# dw 4304
    D dw 4063
    D# dw 3834
    E dw 3619
    F dw 3416
    F# dw 3224
    G dw 3043
    G# dw 2873
    A dw 2711
    A# dw 2559
    B dw 2415

section .text

Cg_note:
    mov ax, [Cg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

C#g_note:
    mov ax, [C#g]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Dg_note:
    mov ax, [Dg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

D#g_note:
    mov ax, [D#g]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Eg_note:
    mov ax, [Eg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Fg_note:
    mov ax, [Fg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

F#g_note:
    mov ax, [F#g]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Gg_note:
    mov ax, [Gg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    call play_note
    ret

G#g_note:
    mov ax, [G#g]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Ag_note:
    mov ax, [Ag]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

A#g_note:
    mov ax, [A#g]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

Bg_note:
    mov ax, [Bg]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

C_note:
    mov ax, [C]
    mov [frequence], ax
    call play_note
    ret

C#_note:
    mov ax, [C#]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

D_note:
    mov ax, [D]
    mov [frequence], ax
    call play_note
    ret

D#_note:
    mov ax, [D#]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

E_note:
    mov ax, [E]
    mov [frequence], ax
    call play_note
    ret

F_note:
    mov ax, [F]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

F#_note:
    mov ax, [F#]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

G_note:
    mov ax, [G]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

G#_note:
    mov ax, [G#]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

A_note:
    mov ax, [A]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

A#_note:
    mov ax, [A#]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

B_note:
    mov ax, [B]
    mov [frequence], ax
    ret

play_note:
    mov al, 182             ; Prepare the speaker for the note.
    out 43h, al             ; Send the value to port 43h.
    mov ax, [frequence]
    out 42h, al             ; Output low byte.
    mov al, ah              ; Output high byte.
    out 42h, al 
    in al, 61h
    or al, 00000011b        ; Set bits 1 and 0.
    out 61h, al             ; Send new value.

    call extendNote
    inc bx
    ret 

extendNote:
    push bx
    mov cx, 9121
    mov bx, 20
    .pause1:
        mov cx, 2500
    .pause2:
        dec cx
        jne .pause2
        dec bx
        jne .pause1

        in  al, 0x61.       ; stop the note
        and al, 11111100b
        out 0x61, al

    pop bx
    ret

movMelody:
    add word [time], 1
    cmp word [time], 120
    jne .skipChangeNote
    mov word [time], 0
    mov bx, [tour]
    cmp bx, 0
    call Gg_note                ; call the sound procedure
    cmp bx, 2
    call C_note
    cmp bx, 4
    call D_note
    cmp bx, 6
    call E_note
    cmp bx, 8
    call Gg_note
    .skipChangeNote:
    call play_note
    ret
```

Comment: The code is asking the [PC speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker) to make those beeps, which it does. If you want to make those come out of the sound card, you would have to send them there. Alternatively you could be asking something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/105564/routing-pc-speaker-sounds-to-the-sound-card) (answer: not really) or you could run under something that emulates the squeaker (dosbox? virtualbox?).

Comment: I don't think you can access io ports directly from a win32 executable. So you are doing an msdos one? Something else?

Comment: @teapot418 If you run a DOS program, the kernel translates accesses to the standard IO devices into appropriate system calls iirc.

Comment: @fuz It could be a kernel driver, you never know... Anyway, assuming it is an msdos exe, this then becomes a question about ntvdm. Which has a sound blaster emulation for making real sounds.